# ST_BestSRID function in PostGIS

Tags: postgis

This [talk](https://youtu.be/GSuZP89UdGs?t=772) by Paul Ramsey mentions that there is a _ST_BestSRID function in PostGIS. I assume it exists to find the best projection when casting unprojected data for other uses.

I cannot find [docs](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/reference.html) on this. Is it actually exposed, and if so, what are the parameters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes that is correct.  The functions that start with _ are not documented because they are what we consider  "private" functions, not for general consumption.

If you look at the functions with smiley faces on this page:  http://postgis.net/docs/PostGIS_Special_Functions_Index.html#PostGIS_TypeFunctionMatrix

You will see they all use this _ST_BestSRID functions (and there are two forms of that function).  The smiley is meant to say these are functions using a hack, and not using pure geodetic calculate.

Study the code behind the smiley face functions and it should be clear how to use _STBestSRID in all its forms.