# How to find good meter-based projection in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system, postgresql, srid

I have a set of point geometries that I would like to cluster together using [ST_ClusterDBSCAN](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_ClusterDBSCAN.html).  Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work for WGS84 and requires a meter-based projection.  Every tutorial that I can seem to find manually determines which projection is a good meter-based projection for their particular dataset.  Is there a generalizable way to do this automatically?

Basically what I'd like to do is take the convex hull of my points, take the centroid of that polygon and then query to find what's a good meter-based projection for that particular region of the world.  I'll then convert my points to this projection and run the clustering.

Comment: What is the 'bounding box' of your data? That is, what area does your data occupy - that will help you determine a UTM zone, for example - which are in metres. Here are the zones: http://www.dmap.co.uk/utmworld.htm

Comment: OK, so basically I want to get the UTM zone for a given point.  If i can figure out which zone the point belongs to like on [this](http://www.dmap.co.uk/utmworld.htm) grid, then how would I get the appropriate SRID?

Comment: If your data spans more than 1 UTM zone, you might want to check into something like Albers Equal Area Conic, which I believe is in Metres... pinging each UTM zone might be tricky...

Comment: you can probably rework the answer from https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/269518/auto-select-suitable-utm-zone-based-on-grid-intersection

Comment: also see http://cite.opengeospatial.org/OGCTestData/wms/1.1.1/spec/wms1.1.1.html#auto_projections.42001 for a way of auto choosing a UTM projection

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're willing to wander into the murky world of undocumented PostGIS functions, you could consider `_ST_BestSRID`. It accepts a `geography` object and spits back a recommended SRID. The code can be seen [here](https://github.com/postgis/postgis/blob/f1f6de48cd205e620e56aca8157080d7a34a6888/postgis/geography_measurement.c#L770) and is well-commented (scroll ahead to line 843) so you can get an idea of the logic used.

Note that the SRIDs for UTM zones returned by this function are internal to PostGIS. They're not EPSG codes and won't appear in `spatial_ref_sys` but are defined in source [here](https://github.com/postgis/postgis/blob/svn-trunk/libpgcommon/lwgeom_transform.h#L42).

Comment: Thanks @dbaston, I came across `ST_BestSRID` [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/177276/st-bestsrid-function-in-postgis) and was hoping to avoid it, but if there is no other option, I guess that'll have to do.

Comment: Do you prefer to avoid it because of the lack of documentation, or are you looking for different logic to select the SRID?

Comment: I just don't want to update my version of PostGIS and have it not be there or be called something else.  I guess I just figured it's private and not-documented for good reason.

Comment: @dbaston the here link is broken would you mind updating it? I am trying to find out what these codes mean

Answer (score 1):

Update based on Ian's comment below...

Use **US National Atlas Equal Area**, assuming your data is in North America

http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/2163/

This coordinate system is already available in PostGIS.

And here are the specs that detail the coordinate system units in metres:

http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/2163/html/

```
PROJCS["US National Atlas Equal Area",
    GEOGCS["Unspecified datum based upon the Clarke 1866 Authalic Sphere",
        DATUM["Not_specified_based_on_Clarke_1866_Authalic_Sphere",
            SPHEROID["Clarke 1866 Authalic Sphere",6370997,0,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7052"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6052"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
        UNIT["degree",0.01745329251994328,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4052"]],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    PROJECTION["Lambert_Azimuthal_Equal_Area"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_center",45],
    PARAMETER["longitude_of_center",-100],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","2163"],
    AXIS["X",EAST],
    AXIS["Y",NORTH]]
```

Comment: If (**and only if**) OP is based in North America, they would be better off using the National Atlas proj (EPSG:2163) as it will already be available.

Comment: @IanTurton I'll update my answer, as that makes more sense... assuming OP is in N. Am!!

Comment: This will actually be world wide, so not assuming North America.

Comment: @Matt ok please add that to your question.